# Error while configuring FLOW3

Tags: typo3-flow

While configuring FLOW3, I get the following error

```
#1315561483: It seems like the PHP binary "C:\php/php" cannot be executed by
FLOW3. Set the correct path to the PHP executable in Configuration/Settings.yaml,
setting FLOW3.core.phpBinaryPathAndFilename.
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration directory, I modified the setting file Settings.yaml.example to Settings.yaml by ist keeping the original and then have uncommented and set the following code at the end of the file

```
#  core:
  #    phpBinaryPathAndFilename: 'C:/path/to/php.exe'
```

as per the path of php exe file.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you should also care about the indentation.

```
--> Don't use Tab but Space
--> Add 2 more spaces for each line as such:

TYPO3:
  FLOW3:
    persistence:
    |
    core:
      phpBinaryPathAndFilename: 'C:/map2/php.exe'
```